# Correlation - weak correlation, no relationship - what conclusion should I make?

Tags: correlation

My hypothesis was that 
1) higher comprehending score is associated with older age 
2) no relationship between distancing score and age. I'm confused as there's no significant correlation between them except negative correlation between comprehending and distancing. Can I make a conclusion in demographic characteristics that minimum and maximum showed that there might be a difference? e.g. distancing in higher in older ages?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is distancing and how do you measure it? Is it connected with Heinz Werner and Bernard Kaplan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From correlation table, you can say that the people with high values on distancing have the tendency of having lower value on comprehending. The age has no relationship with comprehending and distancing.